# Azure DevOps: get suggestions for fields over Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops

I'm trying to push workitems to Azure Dev Ops Server over Rest API.

Two of the fields I want to push over the API are the
created by (`System.CreatedBy`) and the AreaPath (`System.AreaPath`) fields.

Both of the fields rely on pushing an exact string to identify a user
or a "link" in a project I would say.

Is there any way to get an array of possible users to the other side of the REST API, for example for the CreatedBy field I feed the beginning of a second name to the API and the API returns all user-strings that have similar elements in them? Same for the AreaPath?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not available in Azure DevOps REST API. What you said is like a fuzzy query, which is not supported in the related APIs - [`Users`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [`Iterations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

To get the specific values of `System.CreatedBy` and `System.AreaPath`, I think the easiest way is to use [`Work Items - Get Work Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) get an existing work item with the specific values, then you can copy out them and use in the [`Work Items - Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) or [`Work Items - Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/work-items-update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) APIs.